# Is there a way that uses less memory in python to do this

Tags: python, data-science

I am using or-tools to solve an optimization problem. I have many constraints that I am storing in a list. Unfortunately, that takes a lot of memory space.

```
constraints_list = []
for i in range(rows):
    constraints_list.append([0] * (4 * i) + [1, 1, 1, 1] + [0] * ((rows * (columns - 1)) -  ((columns - 1) * (i + 1))))
```

`rows` is in the order of hundreds of thousands, and `columns` is five. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: From the top of my head... use generator? But its feasability might depend on the way you'd like to iterate later on.

Comment: If you need that many values, you need that much space. The question is: do you really need that many values? What are you going to do with `constraints_list` once it's built?

Comment: I will loop through the ``` constraint_list``` that will have the value of the coefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that comes into my head is using compression of some sort. i.e. only storing essential parts of your constraints in the array needed to reproduce the entire constraint. For example:

> [0] * (4 * i)

This is not needed fully. You can simply store `i` and you will know that the first `4 * 1` elements in this array will be 0s. Similarly,

> +[1, 1, 1, 1]

Is not needed, as you already know that after the first `4 * i` elements, the next four will be 1s. Again

> +[0] * ((rows * (columns - 1)) -  ((columns - 1) * (i + 1))))

Is also unnecessary. you can simply store the value  x = `((rows * (columns - 1)) -  ((columns - 1) * (i + 1)))` and you know that the last `x` elements will be 0s as well.

Overall, this is what your code will look like:

```
constraints_list = []
for i in range(rows):
    x = (rows * (columns - 1)) - (columns - 1) * (i + 1)
    new_constraint = [i, x]
    constraints_list.append(new_constraint)
```

Notice that decompression of each `new_constraint` is still constant and finding an element at each index is also fairly easy even with this compressed version. Also, notice that the only variable in `(rows * (columns - 1)) - (columns - 1) * (i + 1)` is `i+1`. So instead of saying x = `(rows * (columns - 1)) - (columns - 1) * (i + 1)`, only x = `i+1` is strictly necessary, although it will probably be easier to not compress it this much.

Edit: I realised that in your specific `constraints_list`, there is absolutely no need to actually store any storage whatsoever. You can simply have a `build_constraint` function that takes `i`, `rows`, and `columns` as arguments. One example could be:

```
def build_constraint(i, rows, columns):
    return [0] * (4 * i) + [1, 1, 1, 1] + [0] * ((rows * (columns - 1)) -  ((columns - 1) * (i + 1)))
```

However, i do realise that this can be quite inconvenient depending on your specific purpose however it is one option. It also is not particularly slow in building the constraint.

Comment: thank you for your feedback. You are right and I can refactor the code and exclude my dependence on storing the constraints.